# In RMarkdown, is there a global option that can be set for all figures and tables to be placed in their own page?

Tags: r-markdown

I am currently working in `knitr` within RMarkdown, and have found it necessary to have all compiled figures and tables to appear in their own separate page. I am doing this by using `\pagebreak` before and after the coding chunk. I am wondering if there is perhaps a global option I can set or program to have all figures/tables appear in their own page. Thank you.

Comment: If you make the figures large enough, they will probably have a page each anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am doing this by using \pagebreak before and after the coding chunk.

It is possible to program what you do using a [`knitr` hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/).

For instance, the following `knitr` hook defines a new `pagebreak` chunk option:

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  if(identical(options$pagebreak, TRUE)) {
    paste("\\pagebreak", x, "\\pagebreak", sep = "\n")  
  } else {
    x
  }
})
```

When this new `pagebreak` chunk option is `TRUE`, it does exactly what you describe: `\pagebreak` is inserted before and after the chunk output.

Therefore, you can use this new chunk option in a code chunk like that:

````
```{r pressure, pagebreak=TRUE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

or set this option for all the chunks in your document with:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(pagebreak = TRUE)
```

Here is a minimal `Rmd` file which uses this hook:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  if(identical(options$pagebreak, TRUE)) {
    paste("\\pagebreak", x, "\\pagebreak", sep = "\n")  
  } else {
    x
  }
})

knitr::opts_chunk$set(pagebreak=TRUE)
```

Some text.

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```

More text.
````